# Pressing a submit button in python using requests

Tags: python

So i want to check if my grades has been uploded, to do that i need to log in a website and then check if it has been changed.
the thing is after you log in you have two buttons: "agree" and "dont agree"
and when i try to press it, the website gives me an error message "wrong use
If you use a Personal Firewall, please deactivate it"

I'll upload my code in few hours

[The website's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuHdw.jpg)

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code. Post the actual code.

Comment: Is that your real user name and password in the code? If so, you should replace those values with dummy values and then do what erip said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python-selenium to press buttons, you can also hide the browser instance.

Comment: How do you hide it? Because I've already wrote half of the code selenium

Comment: USE PhantomJS. Then, change this line:

driver = webdriver.[What ever driver you are using]
to:

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

Answer (score 0):

Like @e4c5 said, you can really push button by python. As for me, the DevTools of Chrome does help a lot.

[Here's the manual of the DevTools.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

The 'Network' tab in DevTools will tell you all the requests and resources in the web page.If you want to see the detail request of the button-pushing action, You can firstly push the button and then see the new request shown in 'Network' tab.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put Referer in the headers. This is how to bypass the university's check. Look at the original request (via Chrome dev tools), and copy the referrer into your request.